# VSCode not showing code suggestions for discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am looking to program a bot for Discord with Python using VS Code and have this snippet of code:

```
@Client.event
async def on_message(message:discord.Message):
    print(message)
```

"message" shows up as type: Any (and so does discord.Message) and offers no code suggestions despite everything having been imported seemingly okay - for instance if I write "discord." in a new line, I get suggestions for modules contained within. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Apologies for a noob question

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you post a snippet or example of what you want VSCode to do? I'm guessing from what you wrote that you are talking about an extension like GitHub CoPilot. If i'm correct in my assumption, try checking to make sure that your extensions on VSCode are all installed properly and working. To get to your extensions in VSCode, you can use Ctrl+Shift+X on Windows, or Cmd+Shift+X on Mac

Comment: Sam, you are absolutely fantastic, that extension is precisely the functionality I was looking for! I'm new to Python and how it handles variables and their types, so I assumed that there is something obvious that I'm missing. But yes, GitHub Copilot seems to be exactly what I was hoping for, thank you so, so much! I'm guessing that same functionality isn't offered by, say, Pylance?

Comment: Im happy to hear that worked for you! I am not sure however, if the same functionality is offered by Pylance or not